# Как заставить бота дискорд отправить случайную картинку из интернета

Tags: python, бот, discord

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой, что моему дискорд боту нужно развиваться. Решил я сделать отправку случайного изображения из интернета, но, сколько не роясь в интернете, я не нашел информации об этом. Можно ли это сделать и желательно через облачное хранения или просто по ссылке альбома ВК или другого, к примеру: поиск по тегу в Гугл.

Пытался использовать банальный код, но он не работает на ссылки.

Простейший код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def SendPepe(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://i.imgur.com/Hab3RJO.jpg")
```

Comment: Xорошо бы добавить код ;)

Comment: Лови...........

Comment: И что не работает?

Comment: Ну, мне нужно, чтоб оно  одну соучайную из огромного количества отправил и как это сделать не представляю, кроме специальных библиотек

Comment: Что у меня не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def SendPepe(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = "Pepe", colour=discord.Colour.dark_green())
    emb.set_image(url = "https://i.imgur.com/Hab3RJO.jpg")
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без кода объяснить, береш картинку из гугл диска или откуда удобно, заучиваешь и отправляешь методами доступными в твоем фреймворке, либо сразу напрямую если Фреймворк предоставляет такую возможность, я даже я если честно не понял суть проблемы дабы это сделать проще пареной репы это ваши базовые навыки чтение запись если нужно рандомную кидать так заведи альбом пробегайся по не му циклом и с помощью random кидай ну или заглядывай в документацию ее специально для вас писали может там уже есть такой метод человек с низу даже привел вам код готовый